# Preciso pegar elementos proximos de um valor dentro de uma lista criada em range python

Tags: python, numpy, range

Estou estudando python e gostaria de entender **como faço para pegar elementos proximos de um valor dentro de uma lista criada em range** e não faço ideia de como proceder no codigo.

```
import numpy as np

lista = np.arange(0.1047, 0.2832, 0.0017)

var = 0.1106
```

a lista criada retorna:

```
[0.1047 0.1064 0.1081 0.1098 0.1115 0.1132 0.1149 0.1166 0.1183 0.12
 0.1217 0.1234 0.1251 0.1268 0.1285 0.1302 0.1319 0.1336 0.1353 0.137
 0.1387 0.1404 0.1421 0.1438 0.1455 0.1472 0.1489 0.1506 0.1523 0.154
 0.1557 0.1574 0.1591 0.1608 0.1625 0.1642 0.1659 0.1676 0.1693 0.171
 0.1727 0.1744 0.1761 0.1778 0.1795 0.1812 0.1829 0.1846 0.1863 0.188
 0.1897 0.1914 0.1931 0.1948 0.1965 0.1982 0.1999 0.2016 0.2033 0.205
 0.2067 0.2084 0.2101 0.2118 0.2135 0.2152 0.2169 0.2186 0.2203 0.222
 0.2237 0.2254 0.2271 0.2288 0.2305 0.2322 0.2339 0.2356 0.2373 0.239
 0.2407 0.2424 0.2441 0.2458 0.2475 0.2492 0.2509 0.2526 0.2543 0.256
 0.2577 0.2594 0.2611 0.2628 0.2645 0.2662 0.2679 0.2696 0.2713 0.273
 0.2747 0.2764 0.2781 0.2798 0.2815]
```

Apartir da variavel **var** gostaria de pegar os items dessa lista proximos do valor **0.1106* que seriam **0.1098** e **0.1115** e não consigo pensar em como passar essa logica pra python pois sou iniciante e estou praticando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá @mmstrok, no numpy existem funções prontas que você pode utilizar para fazer isso, procure na documentação https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html. Porém, pensando lógicamente, desenvolvi um código para te ajudar.

```
import numpy as np
lista = np.arange(0.1047, 0.2832, 0.0017)
var = 0.1106
lista_diferença= []
#laço percorrendo a lista e criando uma outra lista com os valores da diferenças entre as variáveis
for i in range(len(lista)):
  lista_diferença.append(lista[i]-var)
  if lista_diferença[i] < 0:
     lista_diferença[i] = lista_diferença[i]*-1
  else:
     pass

minimo= min(lista_diferença)
index= lista_diferença.index(minimo)
del lista_diferença[index]
minimo_2= min(lista_diferença)
index_2= lista_diferença.index(minimo_2)
print(f'O menor valor mais próximo de {var} é %.4f'%(lista[index]))
print(f'O maior valor mais próximo de {var} é %.4f'%(lista[index_2+1]))
```

Nesse código o que eu fiz basicamente foi criar uma nova lista com o valor absoluto da diferença entre cada elemento da tua lista inicial e o valor de var. Depois disso eu utilizei a função min() do python que retorna o menor valor de uma lista, passando como atributo a lista_diferença que foi criada acima, e então eu verifiquei qual o indice desse valor minimo utilizando a função do python .index(). Então eu salvei esse índice e exclui, utilizando a função del o valor desse índice da lista_diferença, e verifiquei novamente o menor valor, repetindo o passo anterior (fiz isso para verificar as duas menores diferenças que foi o que tu queria fazer). Depois disso, eu apenas printei os valores. Espero ter ajudado, e novamente, a biblioteca numpy apresenta algumas funções prontas para fazer isso.

Comment: cara muito obrigado! estou estudando agora a forma como você solucionou o meu problema e vou dar uma olhada nos doc do Numpy, vlw mesmo!